# If ${a_i} \to 0$ and $\{ {X_i}\} _{i = 1}^\infty $ is a sequence of iid random variables with zero mean, does ${a_i}{X_i} \to 0$ almost surely?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

My problem is slightly more specific than the title of this question: Let $0 < \beta  < 1$ and let $\{ {X_i}\} _{i = 1}^\infty $ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $E({X_i}) = 0$. In addition, I could assume that $E(X_i^2) = {\sigma ^2} < \infty $ if necessary.

Does ${\beta ^i}{X_i} \to 0$ almost surely?

But if the answer is yes, I would be curious to know if the result would also obtain for general real sequences that go to zero. That is when ${\beta ^i}$ is replaced by any ${a_i}$, with ${a_i} \to 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming at least that $\Bbb E|X_j|<\infty$:

Clearly yes if $\sum|a_j|<\infty$; then Chebyschev says that $\sum P(|a_jX_j|>\epsilon)<\infty$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

No in general. Assuming $X_j$ is not essentially bounded there exist $a_j\to0$ such that $\sum P(|a_jX_j|>1)=\infty$, so the less trivial half of Borel-Cantelli says that $a_jX_j$ almost surely fails to tend to $0$.

EDIT: It turns out that there's some confusion, here and in the literature, about exactly what Chebyschev's inequality is. For the record I was talking about this inequality: $$P(|X|>\lambda)\le\frac1\lambda\Bbb E|X|.$$I've been told all my life that's Chebyschev's inequality. Just looked it up, not hallucinating, people do refer to it by that name. They also call it other names, and call other inequalities Chebyschev.

Comment: Note that the first half is using (the first half of) the Borel-Cantelli lemma and therefore doesn't need the independence; it works as long as the $X_i$ are identically distributed, or even just uniformly bounded in $L^1$.

Comment: If we're noting things we should note that mean zero also has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Please, could you provide more detail? I am not a mathematician--just an economist with a tough math problem. I checked the Chebyschev inequality, and I cannot see the relationship with the sumability of the ${a_j}$. One other thing: If $E(X_i^2) = {\sigma ^2} < \infty $, doesn't it follow that $E\left( {\left| {{X_i}} \right|} \right) < \infty $? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb E X^2<\infty$ implies $\Bbb E|X|<\infty$. That's why I assumed the latter - it's assuming less. Chebychev says that $P(|a_jX_j|>\epsilon)\le \Bbb E|a_jX_j|/\epsilon=c_\epsilon|a_j|,$ so the sum of those probabilities is $\le c_\epsilon\sum|a_j|$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich that's Markov

Comment: @Saty, I guess he is mentioning the following version of the Chebyshev inequality $$ \Bbb{P}(|X| > c) \leq \frac{\Bbb{E}\varphi(|X|)}{\varphi(c)}, $$ where $\varphi : [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ is strictly increasing and $c > 0$. Then obviously the Markov's inequality is a special case of this one.

Comment: Yes later I realised

Comment: ??? All I'm using is this: $P(|X|>\lambda)\le\Bbb E|X|/\lambda$. No $\phi$ needed. I see that's sometimes called Markov, but where I come from it's known as Chebyschev. For example Folland _Real Analysis_,  6.17.